# Variable not updating on looping through csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this code which scans the last date in 250 csv files to see if they are euqal to
2021.01.22. Ideally for each csv fiel that has the last row with date 2021.01.22 it would add 1 to the **latest** variable - for some reason it is not adding up - only shows **latest=1** at the end.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

for filename in os.listdir("data"):
    df=pd.read_csv("data/{}".format(filename))
    df2=str(df.iloc[-1,0])
    latest=0
    if df2 == '2021.01.22':
        latest = latest+1

    print(filename)
    print(df2)
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting `latest` for each file in the list.

Try the following:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

latest=0

for filename in os.listdir("data"):
    df=pd.read_csv("data/{}".format(filename))
    df2=str(df.iloc[-1,0])
    if df2 == '2021.01.22':
        latest = latest+1

    print(filename)
    print(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer

latest=0

should be placed before the loop